# MapThread gives different results from ToExpression when trying to assign variables from a list

Tags: assignment

I have the following data set:

```
data = {{"Jakarta","Surabaya","Bandung"},{1,2,3}}
```

and I'd actually like to assign the numerical values to the categorical data so that Jakarta = 1, Surabaya = 2 and Bandung = 3.

If I use `MapThread[Set, {ToExpression[data[[1]]], data[[2]]}]`it works fine but when I try to assign the variables individually I keep on getting error messages:

```
ToExpression[data[[1, 1]]] = data[[2, 1]]
Set::write: "Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[Jakarta] is Protected."
```

However, `ToExpression[data[[1,1]]` works fine

May I know why my second approach is not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it is because `Set` has attribute `HoldFirst`.  The `FullForm` of what you are attempting would look like...

```
Set[ToExpression[data[[1,1]]],1]
```

The `ToExpression` doesn't get a chance to evaluate before trying to assign the value.  You can use `Evaluate` if you insist on doing it this way.

```
Evaluate[ToExpression[data[[1, 1]]]] = data[[2, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I understand the reason now.

Answer (score 10):

I think avoiding `ToExpression` is important, so here is a solution using `Symbol`:

```
MapThread[With[{var = (Clear[#1]; Symbol[#1])}, var = #2] &, data]
```

I use `Clear` to be sure that the symbol has not a previous value defined, which would generate an assigment error.

You can also use `Evaluate` instead `With` as @Andy answer:

```
MapThread[(Clear[#1]; Evaluate[Symbol[#1]] = #2) &, data]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I implemented it in my code and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Set` attempts to assign to the object on the LHS itself, unless that object has head `List`, you are attempting to assign a value to `ToExpression[data[[1, 1]]]` just as the error message informs you.

Also, you will have a problem if your symbol names already have a value when you try your `MapThread` method.  You need a way to get and hold the unevaluated symbol and then pass it to `Set`.  This can be done with `ToHeldExpression` (or `MakeExpression`) as follows:

```
MapThread[
 Set @@ Append[ToHeldExpression@#, #2] &,
 data
]
```

This works by building the arguments for `Set` inside `Hold` and then passing them to `Set` with `Apply` (`@@`).

Doing this for a single element:

```
Set @@ Append[ToHeldExpression[ data[[1, 1]] ], data[[2, 1]] ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I didn't know there was such a command (ToHeldExpression)