# Assigning values to a list of variable names

Tags: assignment, variable-definitions

As part of a calculation I need to do something like this

```
Evaluate[{aaa, bbb, ccc}[[ index]]] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

so if index is `1` then `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` will be stored into the variable `aaa`.
But if I re-evaluate this it does not work because `aaa` is now a list and not a variable. I tried various options with `Hold[]` etc but did not manage to solve this.

Comment: Related: [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2926/121), [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/121), [(3)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2651/121), [(4)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/280/121), [(5)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)

Comment: All: please comment if you believe this question or any of the "Related" ones should be merged.

Comment: By the way please also see: [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a fairly natural question and I feel it is worthy of attention.  I am going to answer in two parts.  First, I am going to show a method that is more appropriate for *Mathematica* programming and which I recommend you use instead.  Then I will show how to force the action you are attempting.

---

## Better Alternatives

The common way to accomplish programmatically selected assignments is to use [indexed variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html).  This allows you to assemble a "variable" from inert parts.  For example, one would use a single variable `var` and simply make assignments (`SeedRandom[1]` for a consistent result):

```
SeedRandom[1]

Do[
  var[i] = RandomInteger[9],
  {i, {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3}}
]
```

Or recall them:

```
var /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

> ```
> {0, 7, 8}
> ```

If you desire a certain name be attached to a value you can index with Strings.

```
names = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};

i = 1;

var[ names[[i]] ] = Sqrt[2]; (* dummy first assignment *)

var[ names[[i]] ] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

var["aaa"]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

In passing, depending on your application you may find [Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Rules.html) applicable.

#### Associations

*Mathematica* 10 introduced [Associations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html) which are like self-contained "indexed variables."  Use is similar but you need to start with an (optionally empty) [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) before you make assignments.  Example:

```
SeedRandom[1]

asc = <||>;

Do[asc[i] = RandomInteger[9], {i, {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3}}]

asc
```

> ```
> <|1 -> 0, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 8|>
> ```

Values may be recalled using [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html), or [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html); for a comparison see:

- [Is there a faster way to Map an Association?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55980/121)

For some ideas of when and why one might use associations over "indexed variables" see:

- [How to make use of Associations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52393/121)

---

## Forcing the behavior

Suppose you *need* the behavior you asked for to keep a large program working without extensive modification.

#### Method #1

This works because [`Part` preserves the head of the expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2450/121), here `Unevaluated`.

Ignore the syntax highlighting in `Unevaluated`: this is a nonstandard but safe use.

This could easily use the same syntax as *Method #2*:  `assign[symbols_, idx_, val_] :=`

```
ClearAll[aaa, bbb, ccc, assign]
assign[idx_, val_] := (# = val) & @ symbols[[1, {idx}]]

symbols = Hold @ Unevaluated[aaa, bbb, ccc];

assign[1, "dummy"];
assign[1, Range@5];

aaa
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

#### Method #2

This uses the [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121) in preference to `Unevaluated`.

```
ClearAll[aaa, bbb, ccc, f1, assign]
assign[symbols_, idx_, val_] := symbols[[{idx}]] /. _[x_] :> (x = val)

symbols = Hold[aaa, bbb, ccc];

assign[symbols, 1, "dummy"];
assign[symbols, 1, Range@5];

aaa
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

Comment: Cool! For Association Lists I would add `ClearAll[assign];
SetAttributes[assign, HoldFirst];
assign[association_, key_, val_] := 
 Hold[association[key]] /. _[x_] :> (x = val)`

Comment: @tchronis You should not need the injector pattern here; a straightforward assignment will work: `SetAttributes[assign, HoldFirst]; 
assign[association_, key_, val_] := association[key] = val`.  Much of the time I would just write out `(asc[#] = #2) &` however if I needed to apply that across a set of keys and values.

Comment: you are right. I overcomplicated things here. When the keys are themselves global variables it can be confusing (that was my case). Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Use functional programming where, whenever you use `aaa`, it is an argument to a function. If you want to pass something different in, call the function.

If you really want to do this, use one of the `HoldAll`-like attributes [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldFirst.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend it, but you could do something like

```
varlist = "var1,var2,var3";
index   = 2;
ToExpression[StringSplit[varlist, ","][[index]] ~~ "={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}"];
var2
(* -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```