Import all files in NotebookDirectory, store each list in a variable with the file name without extension
I have many files stored in the notebook directory, which are called "lista.dat", "listb.dat", ... I would like to import all of them and save them as variables  called "lista", "listb",...
So far I have a few things required, but not figured out all of it.
I set my directory to the correct one with
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

I get all filenames in that directory with
files=FileNames["*.dat"]

I get the name without extension of a certain file in the files list with
FileBaseName[files[[i]]]

I have no idea how I would create a new variable which is named like that.

See: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9974/constructing-variable-names-from-a-string

ClearAll[files];
files=FileNames["*.dat"];
ClearAll[Evaluate[FileBaseName /@ files]];
With[
   {vars = Symbol@*FileBaseName /@ files},
   vars = Import/@ files
]

