# How can I assign some part of data from one list to another list?

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions

I don't know this is correct question or not,but I have a doubt.

I have two `Lists` names are `list1` and `list2`

```
 list1={a,b,c};
 list2={10,20,30};
```

I want to assign `Part[list2,1]` value (10) to the `Part[list1,1]`.that means `Part[list1,1]` act as `Variable`.

after assigning,

If I evaluate `list1`,it will shows `{a,b,c}`,

if I evaluate `list2`,it will shows `{10,20,30}`.

if I evaluate `a`,it will shows `10`.

I want like this..

Is it possible like this?

Comment: seems a bit contradictory...

Answer (score 2):

You can do a direct assignment:

```
{a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3}
```

Then, `a` will return `1`, `b` will return `2` and so on. However, `{a,b,c}` will return `{1,2,3}`.

Answer (score 2):

This general topic has been covered in [Assigning values to a list of variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121) and the questions linked below it.

Within the normal syntax of *Mathematica* you will need a `Hold` or similar device to achieve your objective.  Depending on your *actual use* you will need to select between a number of different methods and compromises.

Understand that `{a,b,c}` cannot be returned raw if `a`, `b`, and `c` have values assigned or you will see the values instead.  To illustrate, you can make the assignments like this:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, list1, list2];

list1 = {a, b, c};
list2 = {10, 20, 30};

Evaluate[list1] = list2;
```

And you can confirm them:

```
?list1
```

> Global`list1
>
> list1={a,b,c}

```
?a
```

> Global`a
>
> a=10

But when you retrieve the value of `list1` you get `{10, 20, 30}` because `a`, `b`, and `c` evaluate.

[Previously I wrote](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121) `step` to conveniently recover such intermediate definitions.

```
step[list1]
```

> ```
>  {a, b, c}
> ```

This is wrapped in `HoldForm` to display these symbols without further evaluation, as can be seen with:

```
step[list1] // InputForm
```

> ```
> HoldForm[{a, b, c}]
> ```