# Use functions to call a named object

Tags: functions, string-manipulation, hold

Now I have several interpolation functions called x30, x50, z30, z50......
I wish to write a function to call these function by inputing x or z and numbers automatically, and assign a argument x to them

I have tried

```
 ("x"<>"30")[x]
```

but not so successful.

Is there any possible method?

Comment: Look up `Symbol[]`.

Comment: I have marked your question as a duplicate.  Please follow the link inserted at the top of your post and read the answers there.  However know that in most cases you should be using a different approach, namely "indexed variables" as [I explained here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6514/121).

Comment: Thank you! This bothered me a long time!