# Evaluation of a list

Tags: evaluation

I'd like to assign to $a[1],\ldots,a[m]$ ($m$ being defined beforehand) zero values. I tried

```
Table[a[i], {i, m}] := Table[0, {m}];
```

but got an error message

```
Set::write: "Tag Table in Table[Sub[Table[0, {i}]], {i, 2, m}] is Protected.
```

**Correction**: Both suggested methods work well but in my particular situation which differs slightly from the above example the former method gives a strange result

```
m := 4;
SubY[i_] := Subscript[y, i];
Table[SubY[i], {i, m}]
Table[SubY[i] = 0, {i, m}];
Table[SubY[i], {i, m}]
Subscript[y, 2]

{y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4}
{0, 0, 0, 0}
y_2
```

while the latter method works perfectly well.

```
m := 4;
SubG[i_] := Subscript[g, i];
Table[SubG[i], {i, m}]
MapThread[(#1 := #2) &, {Table[SubG[i], {i, m}], Table[0, {m}]}];
Table[SubG[i], {i, m}]
Subscript[g, 2]

{g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4}
{0, 0, 0, 0}
0
```

Comment: Don't use subscripts until you get a very good grip on the language. You're calling for trouble

Comment: A big problem in your code is that you can't use `_` in your variables name. If you want to enter y suscripted by 1, you must type y then ^6 then 1 , or use the menus.

Comment: I recommend that you read [(6511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121) and the questions linked from it.  I echo belisarius' warning.  `Subscript` is tricky even for experienced users.

Answer (score 1):

Will this simple method work for you?

```
 m = 5;
 Table[a[i] = 0, {i, m}];
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but actually I need something a bit different. I'm expanding my question.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is already defined

```
SeedRandom[123];
a = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 6]
(* {8, 5, 1, 3, 7, 8} *)
```

and `Length[a]>=m` then

```
m = 4;
a[[;; m]] = ConstantArray[0, m];
a
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 8} *)
```

However, if $a$ not already defined then create with length $m$ of zeros.

```
m = 4;
a = ConstantArray[0, m]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Hope this helps.