# Assign images to elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, image

I would like to assign a list of images of patients to the patient name. To do so I created a list with all the patients names and now I want to assign to every element in the list the correct images. The problem is that Mathematica assign the images to the position in the list not the the element contained in it.

Example:

```
list = {patient1, patient2, patient3, ...}; 
list[[1]] = Import[images]
```

I wish Mathematica allowed `patient1 = Import[images]`, but it doesn't.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: First guess is that Pattern Matching should help.

Comment: Proposed duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121 (see the many **Linked** questions in the right sidebar of that one)

Answer (score 3):

```
patientsNames = {"mickey1", "mickey2", "mickey3"};

patientsImages = {
  Import["http://i.imgur.com/Xppxuqb.gif"], 
  Import["http://i.imgur.com/XBY9QB6.gif"], 
  Import["http://i.imgur.com/d2P3b1Q.gif"]};

patients = MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {patientsNames, patientsImages}]
```

[image]

```
patients[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `Transpose@{patientsNames, patientsImages}` instead of `MapThread`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html).

I'll use [`ExampleData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExampleData.html) instead of [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html).

```
images = Association @@ MapThread[Rule,
    {
     {"patient1", "patient2", "patient3"},
     {
      ExampleData /@ {{"TestImage", "Aerial"}, {"TestImage", "Aerial2"}},
      ExampleData /@ {{"TestImage", "Flower"}, {"TestImage", "Girl"}},
      ExampleData /@ {{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}, {"TestImage", "Splash"}}
      }
     }
    ];
```

The above creates an `Association` where the images can be accessed by the patient's name.

```
images["patient1"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

As you appear to be working with structured data I suggest you read the [Associations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html) guide and the [Computation with Structured Datasets](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ComputationWithStructuredDatasets.html) guide.  There are many functions and features you may benefit from.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Indexed variables can be useful in situations like the one you describe.

Using mrz's nice little set of images

```
patientsImages
```

[image: images]

we can make the assignment with `Do`

```
 Do[patient[i] = patientsImages[[i]], {i, Length[patientsImages]}]
```

then

```
Definition[patient]
```

[image: defs]