# Unevaluated symbols

Tags: symbols, usage-messages

I often find it useful to define a symbol from strings (often in a loop in which I define other symbols). This I accomplish with `Symbol` (and often `ToString`).

However, if the symbol has already been defined, my call to `Symbol` returns not the symbol, but that to which the symbol evaluates.

This may arise rarely, but I stumbled upon it when automatically generating `usage` messages, as in the following example.

```
vars = {x,y};
x$dN = {x1, x2};
y$dN = {y1, y2};
For[ i = 1, i <= Length[vars], i++,
  Evaluate[
    Symbol[
      ToString[vars[[i]]] <> "$dN"
    ]
  ]::usage
  =
  "generic (no argument) thermodynamic quantity vector"
]

(* Symbol::symname: The string "{x1, x2}$dN" cannot be used for a symbol name. 
   A symbol name must start with a letter followed by letters and numbers" *)
```

This is the obvious error because I'm trying to define the `usage` for `x$dN`, which evaluates to `x$dN = {x1, x2}`.

So my question is: can we sometimes leave a symbol unevaluated, yet use it as a symbol?

Comment: Try something like `ReleaseHold@Hold[MessageName][ToExpression["symb", InputForm, Hold], "usage"]`. Using `ToExpression` with a third argument is key here.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom, your solution was easiest for me to instantiate. Thanks!

Comment: Fundamentally this has been covered a number of times before.  Despite this not being an exact duplicate it surely "already has an answer" there:  [(197)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197),
[(783)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783),
[(2651)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2651),
[(2926)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2926),
[(37755)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37755)  Therefore I shall close it to prevent redundant efforts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example it is possible to assign a usage message although the variable has a value. Short example:

```
var = 1;
Function[v, v::usage = "blue", HoldFirst] @@ MakeExpression["var"]
```

The trick is to keep the variable `var` unevaluated all the time which can be tricky.

In my example above this is accomplished by three things:

- `MakeExpression` does what `Symbol` does in your code, but it wraps the result automatically in `HoldComplete`. Therefore, `var` will not be evaluated at this point
- `Function[....,HoldFirst]` creates a functions which too, holds its first argument unevaluated.
- `MessageName` which is the `symbol::msg` operator too holds its first argument. Check `Attributes[MessageName]` to see that.

Comment: halirutan, thanks for the thorough explanation!