# Reading csv/xlsx data into Mathematica with column headings as list names

Tags: import, csv-format

It's old question. However, I could not find satisfactory answer. Decided to post this question. I have a `.csv` file with column heading. How can I import this `.csv` file into *Mathematica* assigning column names as list names in short and sweet way. For example, I can use the following codes.

```
mydata = Import[file, Path -> path];
names = Flatten[mydata[[;; 1]]]; 
Do[listnames[names[[i]]] = 
                     mydata[[2 ;;]][[All, i]], {i, 1, Dimensions[mydata[[2 ;;]]][[2]]}];
```

But I need to write listnames["Col names in .csv file"] to refer to each list. I can not refer `.csv` column names as list names. I need to figure out this because I have over 1000 column headings in my `.csv` data. Please help me to figure out his without long codes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update**

Inspired by [Andy Ross](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/mapthread-gives-different-results-from-toexpression-when-trying-to-assign-variab?lq=1)

> header = First @ iris;
>
> header = StringReplace[header,"."->""](*Because Dot is protected in Mathematica*)
>
> data = Rest @ iris;
>
> assign[name_, value_] := Evaluate[ToExpression[name]] = value;
>
> Thread[ assign[header, Transpose@data] ]

====================================================================

If you are using *Mathematica 10*, there is a new data type called `Dataset`.
Take the iris data for example. Suppose the `iris.csv` is in `d:\`.

```
iris = Import["d:/iris.csv","CSV"];

header = iris[[1]];

data = iris[[2;;]];

irisDataset = Thread[header -> #]& /@ data // Map[Association] // Dataset
```

and it will display like this:

[image]

Please refer to Dataset reference for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes, I am using Mathematica 10. I tried your codes but it does not give me the results I desire. I want the column names of .csv file as list names so that I can refer each .csv column data by their column name as list name in Mathematica. In your example, I should be able to refer each column as a separate list with its name being column heading. I should be able to refer first column as a list as Sepal.Length, second column as another list as Sepal.Width and so on....

Comment: @rkadhikari I advise reading the documentation page for `Dataset` -- it's pretty trivial to take a dataset and extract the raw columns from it, but you might find the `Dataset` itself much easier to work with for some kinds of things.

Comment: Thanks for your time, PhilChang. That's what I was looking for. You are really genius!!:)

Comment: @PhilChang `SemanticImport` makes it really easy to import a tabular file as a `Dataset` if they have a reasonable structure -- no need to parse it to and format it yourself. So for example your code could just be replaced with `SemanticImport["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pydata/pandas/master/pandas/tests/data/iris.csv"]`

Comment: @Taliesin, Thanks for your advice. I will follow your suggestion. I am new to Mathematica, started to like because of friends like you :)

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon,Thank you, SemanticImport is really powerful and amazing!

Comment: @rkadhikari,I feel so flattered, :). I am also new to Mathematica. I like R syntax more. you can fit a linear model just using  mymodel = lm(y~x1+x2+x3,data = mydata). It is so intuitive.

Comment: An alternative way to create a `Dataset` is `irisDataset = 
Dataset[Inner[Rule, header, Transpose[data], Association]]`.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon We use **Excel** files (.XLSX) to import data as well as export data. It provides us with a simple interface that can be understood and used by most people.  Giving columns distinct, complete and reasonable names means the order of the columns does not matter and provides a **named** rather than a **numbered** access to the data.  In this sense `Association` and `Dataset` provide serious progress within *Mathematica*.  In a further step, we also named all rows, which means each cell is identified by pairs of names.  Please do not forget that Excel sheets are regularly sorted.

Comment: @ErnstStelzer, Excellent! you bring me a new understanding of *Inner*

Comment: Thank you all for your time to answer this question. I tried everyone's codes. It seems that I was not able to communicate my concern more clearly. I was not trying to create a Dataset or any data structure. I was just trying to assign .csv column names as list names referring to each column once we import the .csv file into Mathematica. Anyways, PhilChang's updated codes works perfectly fine for my purpose. Thank you guys again.

Comment: @ErnstStelzer you get named rows by using an association of association instead of a list of them.

Comment: The last expression is the use case for AssociationThread: `irisDataset = AssociationThread[header -> #] & /@ data // Dataset`

Comment: @PhilChang You can achieve the same result as in your answer with just `Import` with the `Dataset` representation and the `HeaderLines` option: `Import["d:/iris.csv", {"CSV", "Dataset"}, "HeaderLines" -> 1]`