# Extract part of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, import, associations

I have imported a matrix from a .txt file (it could be better from an Excel file):

```
 {{"", "", "EE", "EE", "EE", "EE", "EE"}, {"", "", "Agriculture", 
  "Forestry", "Fishing", "Mining ", "Extraction "}, {"EE", 
  "Agriculture", "0,131346361", "0,01587348", "0,003638642", 
  "8,36E-004", "1,67E-004"}, {"EE", "Forestry", "5,52E-004", 
  "0,155865778", "4,38E-005", "6,00E-004", "4,00E-005"}, {"EE", 
  "Fishing", "2,33E-004", "4,04E-005", "0,024580636", "4,60E-006", 
  "3,76E-006"}, {"EE", "Mining ", "5,71E-004", "2,78E-004", 
  "5,12E-005", "0,034537603", "3,69E-005"}, {"EE", "Extraction ", 
  "3,67E-004", "2,51E-004", "7,46E-004", "0,001576707", 
  "0,043538054"}}
```

I'll show you the excel file too:

[image]

Ideally I would like to maintain the same layout after I've imported the file in *Mathematica*, so that I can recall a specific number, or a specific row, or a specific sector, or a specific region. I don't know if it is possible to maintain the double headings (EE is an abbreviation for Europe)

Comment: Wrap your matrix in `TableForm` to see it. Extract parts using `Part`.

Comment: This works writing the headings  too? ( to find what i need)

Comment: If your matrix is called `list`, then `list[[1,5]]` is "EE", `list[[2,5]]` is "Fishing".

Comment: ok..yes.. what you're saying is right, i was not clear..sorry..i have to find a way so if i write [EE,Agriculture] i can get the information i need (the entire row i.e)...(this because i just show you an example because i will work on matrix with hundreds of row and columns)

Comment: @AndreaVillabruna, unfortunately, the repeated "EE" are not primary keys by themselves, otherwise can structure your table into a nested `Association` table like this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57189/reading-csv-xlsx-data-into-mathematica-with-column-headings-as-list-names/57192#57192

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lst = {{"", "", "EE", "EE", "EE", "EE", "EE"}, {"", "", "Agriculture",
     "Forestry", "Fishing", "Mining ", "Extraction "}, {"EE", 
    "Agriculture", "0,131346361", "0,01587348", "0,003638642", 
    "8,36E-004", "1,67E-004"}, {"EE", "Forestry", "5,52E-004", 
    "0,155865778", "4,38E-005", "6,00E-004", "4,00E-005"}, {"EE", 
    "Fishing", "2,33E-004", "4,04E-005", "0,024580636", "4,60E-006", 
    "3,76E-006"}, {"EE", "Mining ", "5,71E-004", "2,78E-004", 
    "5,12E-005", "0,034537603", "3,69E-005"}, {"EE", "Extraction ", 
    "3,67E-004", "2,51E-004", "7,46E-004", "0,001576707", 
    "0,043538054"}};
Grid[lst, Frame -> All, Dividers -> Directive[Gray, Thickness[4]], 
 ItemSize -> {Automatic, 2}, 
 Background -> {None, {LightYellow, {LightBlue, LightOrange}}, 
   1 -> LightYellow}]
```

returning this:

[image]

or this, if you want to have the Excel view:

```
 lst1 = {{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"}, {1, "", "", "EE", "EE", 
    "EE", "EE", "EE"}, {2, "", "", "Agriculture", "Forestry", 
    "Fishing", "Mining ", "Extraction "}, {3, "EE", "Agriculture", 
    "0,131346361", "0,01587348", "0,003638642", "8,36E-004", 
    "1,67E-004"}, {4, "EE", "Forestry", "5,52E-004", "0,155865778", 
    "4,38E-005", "6,00E-004", "4,00E-005"}, {5, "EE", "Fishing", 
    "2,33E-004", "4,04E-005", "0,024580636", "4,60E-006", 
    "3,76E-006"}, {6, "EE", "Mining ", "5,71E-004", "2,78E-004", 
    "5,12E-005", "0,034537603", "3,69E-005"}, {7, "EE", "Extraction ",
     "3,67E-004", "2,51E-004", "7,46E-004", "0,001576707", 
    "0,043538054"}};
Grid[lst1, Frame -> All, Dividers -> Directive[Gray, Thickness[4]], 
 ItemSize -> {Automatic, 2}, 
 Background -> {None, {LightYellow, {LightBlue, LightOrange}}, 
   1 -> LightYellow}]
```

yielding this:

[image]

Have fun!

**Later edit**:
To address your question in the comment. It is possible to extract rows or columns corresponding different items, such as "Agriculture" or "Italy". Observing that such item as "Agriculture" is met more than once, I suggest that you do it in a semi-automatic regime, that is, you chose quasi-manually which of them you pick up. Here is how you might do that:

```
Position[lst, "Agriculture"]
```

returns
(*  {{2, 3}, {3, 2}}  *)
corresponding to two different positions of the item "Agriculture". Let us take first of them and pick up the row:

```
    lst[[2, All]]

(*   {"", "", "Agriculture", "Forestry", "Fishing", "Mining ", "Extraction \
"}   *)
```

Now let us take for the same item the column:

```
lst[[All, 3]]

(*  {"EE", "Agriculture", "0,131346361", "5,52E-004", "2,33E-004", \
"5,71E-004", "3,67E-004"}   *)
```

Have fun still!

Comment: can i recall a specific data just writing for example "Agriculture"?

Comment: @Andrea Villabruna What do you mean by "recall a specific data"? If you have in mind to replace ´"Agriculture" ` everywhere by, say, `{1,2,3}`, it's easy. Make `lst/."Agriculture"->{1,2,3}`. Done.

Comment: Sure..if i've imported a matrix whit thousend of rows and columns i would like to have the possibilty to extract a row or a specific data. For example if i want to extract a specific sector or a specific country and i don't know where they are i would like to write "Agriculture" or "Italy" or "Italy-Agriculture" and get the informations i need (and then maybe modify them) @Alexei Boulbitch

Comment: @Andrea Villabruna Have a look at the later edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alexei's answer is great, but I think you could make it easier to grab a column by the label, creating a custom function to do this.

Firstly though, perhaps you want to import the data as numbers, so that you can perform operations on them.  I notice that all the elements after the third row and the third column are in a numeric format where the comma is for the decimal place and `E` is used to denote the power of ten.  This will convert them to a numeric format,

```
lst[[3 ;;, 3 ;;]] = 
  Map[ToExpression[StringReplace[#, {"," -> ".", "E" -> "*^"}]] &, 
   lst[[3 ;;, 3 ;;]], {2}];
```

Then you can look at the table using Alexei's call to `Grid`

```
Grid[lst, Frame -> All, Dividers -> Directive[Gray, Thickness[4]], 
 ItemSize -> {Automatic, 2}, 
 Background -> {None, {LightYellow, {LightBlue, LightOrange}}, 
   1 -> LightYellow}]
```

[image]

Now here are functions that extract rows or columns based on the label,

```
extractRow[label_] := Extract[lst, First@Position[lst[[2]], label]];
extractColumn[label_] := 
 Extract[lst, {All, First@First@Position[lst[[All, 2]], label]}];
```

Edit: The above code works for me, but does not work for OP - perhaps a bug in version 10.0 Windows?  So the functions can be rewritten to use `Part` instead of `Extract`

```
extractRow[label_] := lst[[First[First[Position[lst[[2]], label]]]]];
extractColumn[label_] := 
  lst[[All, First[First[Position[lst[[All, 2]], label]]]]];
```

These work like this,

```
extractRow["Fishing"]
extractColumn["Fishing"]
(* {"EE", "Fishing", 0.000233, 0.0000404, 0.0245806, 4.6*10^-6, 3.76*10^-6} *)
(* {"EE", "Fishing", 0.00363864, 0.0000438, 0.0245806, 0.0000512, 0.000746} *)
```

Comment: extractColumn doesn't work!

Comment: What kind of error message do you get?  It works for me:  http://i.imgur.com/EUzfmbY.png

Comment: I'm not yelling at u ;) ! wait a sec and i'll show you

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/C1shqo5/new

Comment: Curious, what is the output when you enter this text:  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=XLkqs8Ef   (after quitting the kernel and starting fresh)

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/oyTRKXs/new  this is how i've imported the text ( that i think is the same one)

Comment: What is the result when you enter `m[[All,2]]` ?  Copy and paste it here.  Also, what is the result when you type `Position[m[[All,2]],"Agriculture"]`?

Comment: the first one is **{"", "", "Agriculture", "Forestry", "Fishing", "Mining ", "Extraction "}**               and the second one is  _{{3}}_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32392/discussion-between-jason-b-and-andrea-villabruna).