# How to get Symbol["x"]=3 to work

Tags: symbols, assignment

This is probably a really simple one, but I'm stumped.  I want `Symbol["x"]=3` to work just like `x=3`.  However I can't figure out how to get Mathematica to evaluate the `Symbol`, converting the string to the symbol `x`, but then *not* evaluate `x`.

> x = 2
>
> 2
>
> Symbol["x"] = 3
>
> Set::write: Tag Symbol in Symbol[x] is Protected. >>
>
> 3
>
> Evaluate[Symbol["x"]] = 2
>
> Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 3. >>
>
> 2

I know that I can remove the definition, but I have a ton of these and would like to be able to replace their values that have been already set.  `x=3` doesn't require that I remove the definition of `x` to set it.

In case it matters, I'm using 10.0.0.

Comment: This fundamental question has been asked and answered repeatedly: [(197)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197)
[(783)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783)
[(2651)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2651)
[(2926)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2926)
[(37755)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37755).  Please review those and pick the one that you feel is closest, and I will close this accordingly.  Examples of solutions:  `Set @@ Append[ToHeldExpression["x"], 3]` or 
`MakeExpression@"x" /. _[s_] :> (s = 4)`

Comment: And: `ToExpression["x", StandardForm, Function[s, s = 5, HoldFirst]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think I found a possible new solution: `Clear[x];
Activate[Inactive[Set][Symbol["x"],3]]` I agree we can close this question, as a duplicate of [How do you programatically load data into symbols?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/245). Then I'll post my answer there.

Comment: Thanks!  When I searched I didn't find any of those.  The closest is 783.

Comment: Yes, `ToExpression` looks like the right approach.  `ToHeldExpression` is marked as obsolete.

Comment: @MarkAdler Even though I voted to close it, I upvoted your question because it made me think...

Comment: @Jens: `Clear[x]` is not useful, since I would actually have to do `Clear[Symbol["x"]]`, which runs into exactly the same problem.

Comment: While `ToExpression` works, I was hoping for something that gave finer control over evaluation, e.g. allowing only one step of the evaluation to take place.  Control of evaluation has always been a bugaboo for me in using Mathematica.

Comment: So what I did may be a Bad Thing, but it is this: `Unprotect[Set];
Set[s_?StringQ, v_] := 
 ToExpression[s, StandardForm, Function[x, x = v, HoldFirst]];
Protect[Set];`.  Then I can simply `"x"=3` and it works!  `Set` normally gives an error if the left hand side is a string, so I think this is ok.  For me anyway, this is a natural and useful extension of `Set`.

Comment: "Bad Thing" may be putting it mildly. Anyway, in my answer (comment) I used `Clear` only to get a clean slate for my answer to your question, thinking that you were asking only about `Set` here.

Comment: Ah.  I hadn't tried it.  So the `Clear` is not necessary?  The whole point of the question is to not have to clear the definition of `x` first.  If you clear the definition first, then the `Evaluate` works fine, since the symbol `x` evaluated is just `x`.

Comment: @Mark regarding "`Clear` is not useful"` that is not true; see: [(37755)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37755)

Comment: Ah, ok.  I didn't know that `Clear` works on strings.  In any case, I want to be able to do this without clearing the definitions, and your `ToExpression` approach does the trick.

Comment: @Mark Rather than modifying `Set` I recommend that you use an UpSet on a special head as WReach did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/461/121) and I did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17553/121).  **Proposal:** `Set[svar[s_?StringQ], R_] ^:= MakeExpression@s /. _[L_] :> (L = R)` now `svar["x"] = 5` works.  You should probably then `Protect[svar]` to prevent unwanted assignments.

Comment: @MarkAdler Thanks for clarifying the importance of `Clear`ing variables in your question. Looks like @Mr.Wizard has the thing you need...

Comment: @Mark It occurs to me that for programmatic applications your `_?StringQ` *is* probably necessary as you may not have a literal string but rather an expression that evaluates to a string.  I changed my code above to reflect this.