# How to set a value to the symbol denoted by a given string?

Tags: evaluation, hold, symbols

The code `setString[name_String, value_]:= Evaluate[Symbol[name]] = value` fails whenever   `Symbol[name]` has already been assigned a value.

I know of only one way to affect the symbol denoted by a string without triggering further evaluation, and that is the `Clear` function. Said function takes as arguments both symbols and strings denoting symbols. From this

```
setString[name_String, value_]:= Module[{}, 
Clear[name]; 
Evaluate[Symbol[name]] = value]
```

seems like the only solution.

This works, but is this the "correct" solution for the problem? It would not be possible without exploiting the "quirk" of `Clear` to take both symbols and symbol names. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Mathematica could really use an “evaluate just until a pattern is matched” function imo—something that could maybe be written like `Evaluate[Symbol[name], _Symbol]`, for example.

Comment: I think it could be written, for what it’s worth! Mr. Wizard’s infamous (to me, anyway) `step` function could easily be adapted for the job. It would just be nice for it to be built in. If I get back to my computer and no one else has answered with something better, I’ll take a stab at it...

Answer (score 1):

This answer was suggested by @Jens in a comment to [How to set a value to a symbol denoted by a string to work](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58380/how-to-get-symbolx-3-to-work).

```
ClearAll[x,y,setString]
setString[name_String, value_] := (Clear[name]; 
  Activate[Inactive[Set][Symbol[name], value]])

x = 1;
setString["y", 2];
setString["x", 3];

{x,y}   (*  {3,2}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

MMA evaluate arguments before feeding them to a function. Therefore, if `Symbol[name]` already has a value: `value1`

```
Evaluate[Symbol[name]] = value2
```

is equivalent to:

```
value1 = value2
```

what is an error.

To circumvent MMA's evaluation we may e.g. create first a string with the code to set the variable and afterwards execute this string:

```
setString[name_String, value_] := ToExpression[name <> "=" <> ToString[InputForm@value]];
```

with this:

```
val = 2;
setString["val", 5];
val

(*5*)
```

Comment: You should at least use InputForm in your ToString. Consider what happens with `setString["val", 1/2]`.

Comment: Yes, nobody is perfect. I added this. Thank's

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following variation of Daniel's answer:

```
setString[s_String, v_] := ToExpression[s, StandardForm, Function[Null, #=v, HoldAll]]
```

Then:

```
val = 2;
setString["val", 5];
val
```

> 5