# Import names into notebook namespace

Tags: functions, evaluation, syntax, symbols

I have function that at some point has list of strings (e.g. `{"apple","pear"}`) and I want to declare (initialize) those variables in notebook namespace to default value (e.g. `0`) so I could execute in next cell

```
apple+pear
```

It is important that it is done this way - I don't want return from function. (I'm automatically importing variable names and values from Python)

Comment: This one [2926](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2926/5478) or maybe some from links linked there: [6511](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/5478)

Comment: Generally something like `(Evaluate[Symbol[#]] = 0) & /@ {"apple", "pear"}`? if so there is a duplicate, I just can't find it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @Kuba : your code works, thanks! (you can post it as an answer if you want to)